# R: uplad doc file with readtext() with Polish characters

Tags: r, unicode, polish, read-text

Let's have a .doc file (DOC not DOCX!!!) containing following sentence in Polish:

"
Na każde 40 mg% powyżej 100 mg% dodać 1j NovoRapidu, przy glikemii poniżej 100 mg% odjąć 1j NovoRapidu od dawki wyliczonej na WW w posiłku głównym.  Przekąski liczyć 1j/ 1WW. W przypadku hiperglikemii przed snem, tj. ok. godz. 22.00, proszę liczyć na zbicie 1j NovoRapidu na każde 50 mg% powyżej 150 mg%.
"

You may also download the doc file (my_doc.doc) from [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WGTirSJadCaFHDxv2oFrR5HEhP5vhxCJ/view?usp=sharing)

I want to upload this character vector into R by code:

```
library(readtext)
path <- "path of the my_doc.doc"
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "polish")
i <- readtext(path,encoding = "UTF-8")
#or
i <- readtext(path)
i$text

#[1] "Na ka?de 40 mg% powy?ej 100 mg% doda? 1j NovoRapidu, przy  glikemii  #poni?ej\r\n100 mg% odj?? 1j NovoRapidu od dawki wyliczonej na  WW  w  posi?#ku  g?ównym.\r\nPrzek?ski liczy? 1j/ 1WW. W przypadku  hiperglikemii  przed  #snem,  tj.  ok.\r\ngodz. 22.00, prosz? liczy? na zbicie 1j NovoRapidu na ka?#de 50  mg%  powy?ej\r\n150 mg%."
```

The code gives the same output independently from the used encoding.
I want to obtain the same text in both .doc file and R.
I use Windows. 
How shall I edit my code?

Comment: Maybe encoding is not utf but windows-1250? Then it can be reencoded to utf-8

Comment: It gave the same character vector without polish characters. :(